# Vertical harpoon (half-arrow) notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, topological-groups

I am studying a paper about Subgroups of Infinite Symmetric Groups by Macpherson and Neumann; throughout the paper, the authors use the notation $\upharpoonright$.

For example, when they seek to topologize an infinite symmetric group $Sym(\Omega)$, they define the closure of a subset $X$ of $Sym(\Omega)$ as such:

$\{f \in Sym(\Omega)  \ |$ for all finite subsets $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $x\upharpoonright\Phi=f\upharpoonright\Phi\}$

The authors don't define this notation, but they use it in several proofs. What do the authors mean when they use it?

Comment: It denotes the restriction of a function to a subset of its domain.

Comment: Sometimes it is more usual to see it as $\;f\upharpoonright_\Phi\;$ , for example.

Comment: Indeed, the notation I usually see for a restriction is $f|_\Phi$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the truncation of a function to a particular set. That is, the subset of the function that has first-entries from the particular set.

Comment: I see, then it's a simpler concept than I thought. Thanks for the answer!